# RavenDb only stores empty objects

Tags: c#, ravendb

I want to store some data in RavenDb but only empty objects in RavenDb are stored.

This is my code:

```
using (var uow = new ReadOnlyUnitOfWork(new AistoDbContext()))
{
    result = uow.Repository<Projekt>().GetProjectStammdaten().ToList();

    using (IDocumentSession session = _store.OpenSession())
    {
        foreach (var data in result)
        {
            session.Store(data);
            session.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

result has some data:

[image]

But when i look in RavenDb Studio nothing but the indexes are stored:

[image]

Does anybody have a clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meanwhile we have found the problem and were able to solve it!

The class we would like to store in RavenDb was decorated with a `[DataContract]` looked like this:

```
[DataContract]
public class ProjektStammdaten
{
    public DateTime AeTerminStammhaus { get; set; }

    public DateTime? AeTerminTochter { get; set; }
```

we forgot to add the `[DataMember]` Attribute to the properties we would like to store in RavenDb

```
[DataContract]
public class ProjektStammdaten
{
    [DataMember]
    public DateTime AeTerminStammhaus { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public DateTime? AeTerminTochter { get; set; }
```

After attributing the class we have been able to store the entries!

Answer (score 0):

The most likely reason is that your object inherits from a `List<T>` or `IEnumerable<T>`. 
You cannot store those as objects unless you write a `JsonConverter` for them.

Comment: in the meanwhile we have found the problem. I have written the solution as an answer. Thanks for giving me a hint! Really appreciate it!